# Shift Cipher in C

Tags: c, encryption, shift

I am making a program that adds a specific number to the ASCII value of every character in a string. The code gives me a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when running. What am i Doing wrong? I am new to C.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    char x[1000],y[1000];

    printf("String:");
    gets(x);

    printf("\nShift:");
    scanf("%d",a);

    b=0;
    printf("\n");

    while (b < strlen(x))
    {
        c=x[b] + a;
        printf("%c",c);
        b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf("%d",a); make it scanf("%d",&a);

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

and try again.